# Speed up for loop operations in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, confidence-interval

I have wrote a simulation code for censored observations to find bootstrap-t confidence interval. However, the runtime for my code is too long sometimes it took 3-4 days just to run one full coding. I need to simulate it at various sample sizes and censoring proportions so time is really important for me.

I did put break statement but it did not work. Do you guys have any idea on how to speed up the runtime?

This is my code :

```
#BOOTSTRAP-T (20%)

library(survival)
n = 100
N=1000
alpha = 1
lambda = 0.5
alphaHat = NULL
lambdaHat = NULL
cp = NULL
btAlpha<- matrix (NA , nrow = N, ncol = 2)
btLambda<- matrix (NA , nrow = N, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1 :1000){
 if(i>50){
  break
 }
 u <-runif(n)
 c1 <-rexp(n,0.1)
 t1 <- -(log(1-u^(1/alpha))/lambda)
 t <-pmin(t1,c1)
 ci <-1*(t1<c1) #censored data
 cp[i]<-length(ci[ci==0])/n #censoring proportion


 #FUNCTION TO CALL OUT
 estBoot<-function(data,j)
{
  dat <-data [j,]
  data0 <-dat [ which ( dat$ci==0) ,] # right censored data
  data1 <-dat [ which ( dat$ci==1) ,] # uncensored data
  dat


#MAXIMUM LIKELIHOOD ESTIMATION  
library(maxLik)
LLF <-function(para)
{
  alpha <-para[1]
  lambda <-para[2]
  a <-sum(log(alpha*lambda*(1-exp(-lambda*data1$t1))^(alpha-1)*exp(-lambda*data1$t1)))
  b <-sum(log(1-(1-exp(-lambda*data0$t1)^(alpha))))
  l <-a+b
  return(l)
}
mle<-maxLik(LLF,start=c(alpha=1,lambda=0.5))

alphaHat=mle$estimate[1]
lambdaHat=mle$estimate[2]

observedDi=solve(-mle$hessian)

return(c(alphaHat,lambdaHat,observedDi[1,1],observedDi[2,2]))
}

library(boot)

bt<-boot(dat,estBoot,R=1000)


bootAlphaHat<-bt$t[,1] #t is from bootstrap
bootAlphaHat0<-bt$t0[1] #t0 is from original set
seAlphaHat<-sqrt(bt$t[,2])
seAlphaHat0<-sqrt(bt$t0[2]) #same as 'original' in bt
zAlpha<-(bootAlphaHat-bootAlphaHat0)/seAlphaHat
kAlpha<-zAlpha[order(zAlpha)]
ciAlpha<-c(kAlpha[25],kAlpha[975])
btAlpha[i ,]<-rev(bootAlphaHat0-ciAlpha*seAlphaHat0)


bootLambdaHat<-bt$t[,2]
bootLambdaHat0<-bt$t0[2]
seLambdaHat<-sqrt(bt$t[,4])
seLambdaHat0<-sqrt(bt$t0[4])
zLambda<-(bootLambdaHat-bootLambdaHat0)/seLambdaHat
kLambda<-zLambda[order(zLambda)]
ciLambda<-c(kLambda[25],kLambda[975])
btLambda[i,]<- rev(bootLambdaHat0-ciLambda*seLambdaHat0)
}

leftAlpha <-sum(btAlpha[,1]>alpha)/N
rightAlpha <-sum(btAlpha[,2]<alpha)/N
totalEAlpha <- leftAlpha + rightAlpha

leftLambda <-sum(btLambda[,1]>lambda)/N
rightLambda <-sum(btLambda[,2]<lambda)/N
totalELambda <- leftLambda + rightLambda

#alpha=0.05
sealphaHat <-sqrt(0.05*(1-0.05)/N)

antiAlpha<-totalEAlpha >(0.05+2.58 *sealphaHat)
conAlpha<-totalEAlpha<(0.05-2.58 *sealphaHat )
asymAlpha<-(max(leftAlpha,rightAlpha)/min(leftAlpha,rightAlpha))>1.5

antiLambda<-totalELambda >(0.05+2.58 *sealphaHat)
conLambda<-totalELambda<(0.05-2.58 *sealphaHat )
asymLambda<-(max(leftLambda,rightLambda)/min(leftLambda,rightLambda))>1.5


anti <- antiAlpha+antiLambda
con <- conAlpha+conLambda
asym <- asymAlpha+asymLambda
```

Comment: `for(i in 1:1000) { print(i) if(i>50) break}`, when you installed R did you enable profiling, as those results would guide to where your bottle necks are with Profviz. What operation seems to take the longest?

Comment: Your code is very hard to read, as I noted in your last post. You should really consider an  [R Style guide](https://jef.works/R-style-guide/).

Comment: Your code is not runnable. When `bt<-boot(dat,estBoot,R=1000)` is called `dat` is not defined, it is only a variable name inside `estBoot`

Comment: Load packages just once. NOT inside loops. Start with small values for “i”. Explain why you are doing bootstraps inside a simulation loop. Bootstrap methods are for estimating statistical features. Simulations are another way. But there not typically a reason to do both.